# Detect beacon without hard coding UUID in Android app

Tags: android, kotlin, beacon, eddystone

I want my app to display a notification when it is in the vicinity of a beacon. But I don't wanna hard code the UUID of the beacon in my program. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

1. Simply omit the ProximityUUID in the Region definition when scanning for beacons and the AndroidBeaconLibrary will detect all beacons regardless of UUID.
2. include the ProximityUUID in the Region definition, but fetch the value from a web service call you make first.  This way, you can change the UUID on your server whenever you want without having to update your app's hard-coded value.

Comment: Suppose I have the KFC app. I want the app to display a notification when I am near KFC. But in my code, I mustn't mention the UUID of the beacon present in KFC. Many beacons will be present in the stores near KFC ( McD, Dunkin Donuts, etc.). But notification should be displayed only when I am near KFC

Comment: I think KFC is delicious so I'd love a notification when one is nearby!  (Full disclosure: I am a very minor shareholder). Seriously though, if you do not want the UUID on the code, then using a server to fetch it at runtime is a fine solution.